# insert string and new line before pattern match using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to search a pattern and then add multiple lines before that pattern match in a file using `sed`. I know about adding lines after a `regex` using `sed`. But I am not able to figure out how to do that in this particular case.

```
Example: file.txt
I am here-1.
I am here-2.   
I am here-3.
```

I want to add few lines before pattern `3`. So output file should look like:

```
I am here-1.
I am here-2.
NEW LINE 1.
NEW LINE 2.
NEW LINE 3.
I am here-3.
```

This is what I am trying: `sed '/3/ i NEW LINE 1.{G;} NEW LINE 2.{G;} NEW LINE 3.{G;}' file.txt >> file.txt`

But it is not adding any newlines rather it is printing `{G;}`. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/3/ i NEW LINE 1.\nNEW LINE 2.\nNEW LINE 3.\n' file.txt
```

Comment: Since the command i insert a newline, the trailing newline character is implicit, you can remove it.